# @PostFilter on Optional

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I would like to use `@PostFilter` on method returning `Optional`.

Spring `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` currently not handling `Optional` but I could make a simple decorator and transform the `Optional` into `Stream`. How can I register such decorator without creating a new `GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration` as I am using an internal framework I can't modify.

Is there another way to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was as simple as declaring the decorator as a `@Service`

```java
@Service
public class OptionalAdapterMethodSecurityExpressionHandler implements MethodSecurityExpressionHandler {

    private final MethodSecurityExpressionHandler handler

    public CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler(MethodSecurityExpressionHandler handler){
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    @Autowired
    public CustomMethodSecurityExpressionHandler(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this(new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler());
        ((DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler)this.original).setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    }

    @Override
    public Object filter(Object filterTarget, Expression filterExpression, EvaluationContext ctx) {
        if (filterTarget instanceof Optional) {
            final List<?> optionalUnfilteredList = ((Optional<?>) filterTarget).stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

            final List<?> optionalFilteredList = (List<?>) this.handler.filter(optionalUnfilteredList, filterExpression, ctx);
            return optionalFilteredList.stream()
                .findFirst();
        }
        return this.handler.filter(filterTarget, filterExpression, ctx);
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The easier way to do it is like this:

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.springframework.expression.EvaluationContext;
import org.springframework.expression.Expression;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
import org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.MethodSecurityExpressionHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class AnyTypeMethodSecurityExpressionHandler extends DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler implements MethodSecurityExpressionHandler {
    @Override
    public Object filter(final Object filterTarget, final Expression filterExpression, final EvaluationContext ctx) {
        if (filterTarget instanceof Collection || filterTarget != null && filterTarget.getClass().isArray() || filterTarget instanceof Stream) {
            return super.filter(filterTarget, filterExpression, ctx);
        }
        if (filterTarget instanceof Optional) {
            return ((Stream<?>) super.filter(((Optional<?>) filterTarget).stream(), filterExpression, ctx)).findAny();
        }
        return ((Stream<?>) super.filter(Stream.ofNullable(filterTarget), filterExpression, ctx)).findAny().orElse(null);
    }
}
```

That will handle `Optional`s and also plain Java Objects (making them `null` if they are filtered).

Comment: This is great, but not perfect; it uses a Java language profile later than either Spring or `Optional` requires.

Comment: You forgot the Map type the `DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler` supports